# Rundeck Job List View plugin installation issue

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying out and exploring the plugins available in Rundeck. I'm trying to install Job List View plugin because I want to see the statistics of my jobs but after installing I still can't see the job list view. Then whenever I restart Rundeck service, then go to Plugin repositories, the plugin needs to be installed again even though I've clearly installed the job list view plugin before. I can't see any errors in **service.log**.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

My Rundeck version is 3.3.5

Comment: Hi! What kind of installation are you using? (DEB, RPM, WAR or Docker-based)

Comment: Hello @MegaDrive68k, I'm using war. I'm running my Rundeck on a Windows OS.

Comment: I reproduced your issue (only happens on Windows, on Linux based systems, works OK), and testing a bit it seems that the plugin cache isn't created for that specific plugin (but the `.zip` file is present on the `libext` directory). Can you open a new issue here? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues

Comment: Hey @MegaDrive68k, done opening a new issue. For reference, the issue number is #6617. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug reported [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6617) (by the question author). Anyway, you can get the job info via API, I leave some examples using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to "beautify" the output:

1. To get [All jobs](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#listing-jobs) from a project:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="your_rundeck_node"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="cqgfZlrSF84oUoC2ZzRwiltiyefjZx9R"

# specific api call info
rdeck_job="5dc08e08-0e28-4a74-9ef0-4ec0c8e3f55e"
rdeck_project="YourProject"

# get the job list from a project
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/jobs" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" | jq
```

2. Get all job [metadata](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#get-job-metadata):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="your_rundeck_node"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="cqgfZlrSF84oUoC2ZzRwiltiyefjZx9R"

# specific api call info
rdeck_job="5dc08e08-0e28-4a74-9ef0-4ec0c8e3f55e"

# get the job metadata
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/job/$rdeck_job/info" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" | jq
```

3. Get job [forecast](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#get-job-forecast) information:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="your_rundeck_node"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="cqgfZlrSF84oUoC2ZzRwiltiyefjZx9R"

# specific api call info
rdeck_job="5dc08e08-0e28-4a74-9ef0-4ec0c8e3f55e"

# get the job forecast
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/job/$rdeck_job/forecast" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" | jq
```

More info about Rundeck API [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html), and [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k) a lot of useful examples.